# Navigation Drawer items animate only once

Tags: android, animation, navigation-drawer, notifydatasetchanged

I have a navigation drawer with 5-10 items. I have added animation to those items so that they slide from left-to-right. The problem is this happens only the first time I open the drawer, during rest of the time there is no animation. As a remedy, I add notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter inside onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) method. Now the items animate everytime, but it's effect is like

1. All items enter without animation.
2. Then all items are recreated right in front of me.
3. Then they animate.
   Hope you all get an idea.

So what I want is => The Navigation Drawer items must animate left-to-right every time I open the drawer, with swipe and also on clicking the nav-toggle.

Some code snippets of mine to give idea what I did
Inside Adapter which inflates the view:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, LayoutInflater inflator, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.base_drawer_nav_item, parent, false);
            ImageView nav_item_icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nav_item_icon);
            TextView nav_item_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nav_item_title);
            nav_item_icon.setImageResource(this.icon);
            nav_item_title.setText(this.title);
        }
        if(convertView != null)
            setAnimation(convertView, position);

        return convertView;
    }

    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
        if(mContext != null) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);

            animation.setDuration(position * 50 + 200);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    }
```

Inside activity where Navigation drawer is- in onCreate() method(Please note that I have add notifyDataSetChanged only as a remedy which sure doesn't work as I expected)

```
//some code above and below this

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
```

Another thought that I have is, that I should keep all the view in an ArrayList and then animate then everytime navigationDrawer is opened (using for loop + animation.start()) Though I didn't implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Your method setAnimation() is not setting animation, but rather calling it and executing it once. So every time you want to animate rows (e.g. for swipe or click) you would have to call setAnimation()

EDIT: notifyDataSetChanged works because it calls getView() method in adapter which will at the end call your setAnimation()

EDIT2: Maybe something like this: move your setAnimation() from adapter. Now, there are few solution, but just put it in MainActivity, and then make this method:

```
public void setAnimation(int position){
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    animation.setDuration(position * 50 + 200);
    drawerListView.getChildAt(position).startAnimation(animation);
}
```

This will animate one row and you can easily call it from main activity.

If you want all rows animated you could do it in for loop and call every position, but better approach would be using [AnimationSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html).

Comment: Can you please tell me the correct way which I should follow, possibly with the help of some code

Comment: If it worked please mark as answer. If you need more help with it you can ask here.